# Какую лицензию для программы (open source) лучше использовать?

Tags: лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Основные моменты (условия распространения):

Разрешается распространение, доработка и создание производных работ при условии:

1. Коммерческое использование допускается только с разрешения автора;
2. Производные работы должны содержать сведения об авторе и ссылку на вебсайт;
3. При создании производных работ необходимо проинформировать об этом автора.

Comment: используйте двойное лицензирование. к примеру gpl+собственная лицензия.

Хотя никто не мешает прям так и описать лицензионные соглашения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Коммерческое использование допускается только с разрешения автора;

Это non-free, соответственно, ни одна готовая FLOSS-лицензия Вам, если нужно такое требование, не подойдет.

Пишите свою EULA.

Comment: Хорошо, а если убрать этот пункт, то тогда? Подразумеваю что Apache... ?

Comment: Нет, потому что 3-й пункт тоже несвободный.